# alignment of button in bootstrap isnt displaying correctly on Angular UI

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-3">Category List</h1>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end-mt-3"> 
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Category</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

here Alignment of Category List and add Buttons are not correct . I tried adding auto margin as my screen but its not displaying the buttons and list correctly.

[image]

I tried adding auto margin as my screen but its not displaying the buttons and list correctly.

I want the alignment

[image]

Comment: You've erroneously merged two class names with a hyphen.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such class as `justify-content-end-mt-3` in Bootstrap 5. It should be `justify-content-end`.

Comment: This should be a comment alongside flagging for closure as a typo.